# AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'sharex'

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have some code that works perfectly on my local machine with Python 3.7 but fails on a distant server with Python 3.7 also.
What is weird is that the fail error is `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'sharex'`. Yet, `AxesSubplot` should have a `sharex` as an attribute so I don't understand where it can come from.
For debugging, here is a very short piece of code that doesn't work on my distant server:

```py
import numpy as np ; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.arange(50) ; y = x

title='test'
plt.close(title)
fig=plt.figure(title, clear=True)
fig.suptitle(title)
ax1,ax2=fig.subplots(nrows=2)
ax1.sharex(ax2)
```

Do you see what can be the origin of the problem?

Comment: It might be useful to compare the versions of matplotlib installed on both machines (and mention the version numbers in your question).

Comment: You are right. On the distant server the version is 2.2.3 whereas it is 3.4.1 on my local machine. Now it works !
Thanks

Comment: I undid your last edit, since answers should NOT be posted in the question, but as an answer (I did post a full answer now). Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. Please take the short [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) if you're not yet familiar with the site.. You might also want to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). By the way, compliments on the [mre] - this really helped!

Answer (score 1):

Since the code is running correctly on one of your computers, the problem does not seem to be in the code itself. So the first thing that comes to mind is checking the versions of your installed `matplotlib` libraries. It could be that this method does not exist in all versions.

Looking at the documentation of the Axes class, you can see that the `sharex()` method is documented in [version 3.3](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/axes_api.html#module-matplotlib.axes), but not in [version 3.2](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/axes_api.html#module-matplotlib.axes). So one of the computers is probably running an older version and upgrading to version 3.3.0 or higher should solve the problem.

You already [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71937207/3) that for versions lower than 3.3 it can also be solved by using:

```py
ax1.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax1,ax2)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the error is coming from this line here:

```
fig=plt.figure(title, clear=True)
```

Remove the clear=True bit and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunatly it doesn't work neither without the clear=True.